# I am trying to install Parcel globally using the npm parcel -g command

Tags: javascript, html, css, parcel

I am trying to install Parcel globally using the npm parcel -g command and I get an error message when I use parcel index.html stating no entries found.  What can I do to fix this?

Here is the command I enter to install parcel globally.

PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Moshify> npm i -g parcel-bundler
npm WARN deprecated parcel-bundler@1.12.5: Parcel v1 is no longer maintained. Please migrate to v2, which is published under the 'parcel' package. See https://v2.parceljs.org/getting-started/migration for details.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up tonpm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\parcel -> C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\bin\cli.js

> parcel-bundler@1.12.5 postinstall C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler
> node -e "console.log('\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove Parcel? You can now donate to our open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[34mhttps://opencollective.com/parcel/donate\u001b[0m')"

Love Parcel? You can now donate to our open collective:

> https://opencollective.com/parcel/donate
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\parcel-bundler\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- parcel-bundler@1.12.5
  updated 1 package in 25.129s

Here is where I try to call the server and the error message I am getting.

PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Moshify> parcel index.html
Server running at http://localhost:1234
×  No entries found.
at Bundler.bundle (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:275:17)
at async Bundler.serve (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:842:7)
at async Command.bundle (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\cli.js:241:20)

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to initialize you npm package for package.json file.

using that command `npm init -yes` . Create a default package.json file.

Then need to install it globally using this command :

```
npm install parcel-bundler -g
```

Also you can try to save it in your package.json file.

```
npm install parcel-bundler -g --save-dev
```

Comment: I tried that and it is giving the same result.  Is there anyone who can set up a zoom session with me to take a look at my work.  I can pay.

Comment: can I see your package.json file? and give me your whatsapp number that can I see.